# Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying this code and get an error when running it.

```
   $cfg->{'validRules'} = "true"
...


if ($cfg->{'validRules'} eq "true") { <== error is pointing to this
}
```

Error is

> Error: Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
>   at

I am totally clueless. I tried changing it but still the same. Appreciate if I can get some help.

Comment: What happens between the assignment and the access? Is `$cfg` being passed to a `sub` somewhere along the way?

Comment: `Data::Dumper` is your friend.

Comment: @mu yes $cfg is modified and infact $cfg->{'validRules'} is added if certain condition is satisfied. this happens in another sub and the $cfg is returned to the caller. now the caller calls the next sub to which $cfg is being passed and in that sub, i see the issue reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did something equivalent to

```
$cfg = 0;
```

at some point. This will obviously make

```
$cfg->{'validRules'}
```

fail. Find where you assign zero to `$cfg` and fix it.

Comment: if (exists($cfg->{'validRules'}) && $cfg->{'validRules'} eq "true") { <== error is pointing to this
} I still see the same error

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothala `exists` still tries to use the `$cfg` variable as a reference.

Comment: so what is the best way to check ?

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothla: You can check using `if (ref $cfg eq 'HASH')` but the right way is to fix the bug that has corrupted `$cfg`.

Comment: When I use dumper, I see the whole hash of $cfg which contains 'validRules'

Comment: trying dumper
$VAR1 = { 'something' => { 'me'=> 'true' }, checkit=>{},
  'validRules' => 'true'
};

Comment: another scenario is  $VAR1 = { 'something' => { 'me'=> 'true' },checkit=>{}};

Comment: my dumper is doing this print (Dumper($cfg));

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothala: Are you dumping `$cfg` *at the point you get the error*? You should put it immediately before the `if` statement that fails.

Comment: @ikegami how about  $cfg = { 'something' => { 'me'=> 'true' },checkit=>{}}. if I do if (exists($cfg->{'validRules'}) && $cfg->{'validRules'} eq "true") shouldnt it take it?

Comment: @Borodin yes right before if I put the dumper. I dont see the dump but I see the error

Comment: @ikegami The code is part of a bigger infra that we are using. I cant copy/paste it. I just tried again and I see Error: Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ...

Comment: @SreeramRavinoothala Repeating your error again is not going to help. You mention passing $cfg to a sub, perhaps you should show that code.

Comment: @ikegami, let me check by removing the if condition and get dumper output. In case, it happens is there a better way of checking if?

Comment: The `if` is fine. As I said in my answer, the problem is that you're putting zero in `$cfg`.

Comment: yeah, another sub was not returning all the values which includes $cfg. so caller got empty. Thanks for pushing me to look at the code more.